# Using polyglot notebooks in Visual Studio Code how can you autoimport missing namespaces for .NET C#

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, polyglot, polyglot-notebooks

Using polyglot notebooks in VS Code with .NET8, I cannot seem to figure out how to trigger the autoimport functionality, "Quick action", normaly used with dotnet development.

I have checked that the setting is turned on and working in a normal Console application setup:
[From VS Code settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GYo0.png)

(SettingsID in JSON format is *dotnet.completion.showCompletionItemsFromUnimportedNamespaces*.)

F.ex. in a .dib notbook:

```cs
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("/AnExample/FilePath", FileMode.Create))
{
  ...
}
```

This will not give me a "Quick action" to import the missing namespace, System.IO.

But when I am in a normal .NET Console application setup, I will get this "Quick action" automatically as shown below:
[From VS Code "Quick action" import missing namespcae](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu7c5.png)

Comment: I second this question ✌️

Comment: Looks like this is not existing functionality and therefor submitted a feature request on [.NET Interactive repo for Polyglot Notebooks](https://github.com/dotnet/interactive/issues/3473)

Comment: Please update the thread if you get an update or catch a workaround. @Mari T-J

Comment: Yes, I will do so!